# What are the advantage of running a penetration test through Docker?

Tags: penetration-test, kali-linux, docker

I was looking at Kali's [blog post about its official Docker image](https://www.kali.org/news/official-kali-linux-docker-images/), and I was wondering what the real benefits are.  Why would I would run penetration testing through a docker image?  Is it something about automating testing? Is it just because it's clean and easy to setup?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You got it.  The primary benefit comes from having every new engagement start with a known fresh copy.

Everything is set up and ready to go.  You're guaranteed that nothing from previous engagements is still there.  (That could be a serious liability if confidential information leaked from one client to another).

Internally, you could have a tool which spins up a fresh testing platform, scans your network, sends a report, and then shuts down.